# "Scientific" explanation for magic?

Tags: science-based, magic

Physics does not allow for magic. In fact, magic is pretty much defined as "Cool stuff physics doesn't allow".

But what if it did?

Usually, magic is explained away simply as fantastical, for understandable reasons - it is. However, is there any way to take a different approach - to add magic into physics?

To be more specific, my question is: what is a relatively minor adjustment to the laws of physics that could permit magic? Physics is still the same in most cases; only difference is that magic is added in. There are laws of magic, equations defining the behavior of magic, etc.

How could this be done?

Comment: Making still pictures without the need of a skilled draughtsman or painter was considered magic. Viewing things which are happening in distant places, or which have happened a long time ago, or which never happened, was considered magic. Talking to people across the world as if they were in the same room was considered magic. Having an artificial assistant who listens to your voice and obeys commands was considered magic. Seeing the inside of a living human body without killing it was considerd magic. *So much magic has been introduced in our lives!* What does *your* magic do?

Comment: In order to allow for magic, you have to define it. Physics can't sufficiently explain many things, like dark matter or dark energy, but it has to allow them to exist, until a satisfactory explanation is made.

Comment: To quote the user who answered this question "I don't know what you want to do with your magic". If you don't tell us, we cannot answer.

Comment: This is because as we developed Science, we took all the Magic that worked and said it was now Science and not Magic at all.  Drinking willow bark tea used to be Magic.

Comment: Bear in mind, Arthur C. Clarke once stated, "A sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." So physics accommodates magic just fine. It's when you don't want to explain it with technology that it fails - and the reason why the question was closed. "Inventing physics" to accommodate magic is quite literally inventing your magic system for you. That's beyond the scope of this site. But we're happy to help you invent it. Where would you like to start? There's always a price for using energy (thermodynamics). What price do your magic users pay?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new set of laws to physics, the '(Insert scientist name here)'s X Laws of Magic'. Now, I don't know what you want to do with your magic, but here are a few suggestions on how this law would go. If magic is limited to a few creatures (ie. fey, goblins, unicorns, etc.) then it would be more of a biological thing but your new physics law will still apply to them.

What you do with your laws of magic is entirely up to you, so you choose to do whatever fits your purpose which might not be these, could be one of them, could be all of them, could be one of these combined with another answer, *you choose what works best for you*.

Option 1- The Eragon Laws.

'Casting a spell requires as much energy as it would take one to do the action themselves.' Weaker spell casters like the old man in the library won't be able to cast as many spells as the hulking schoolyard bully simply because the schoolyard bully is able to expend more energy. This is what is used in the Eragon series for magic rules and, for the most part, made sense and worked.

Option 2- Alternate Dimension Laws

'One can access alternate dimensions and use energy from there to cast a spell.' If you want to go into alternate dimensions for your story, then this option works well but if you aren't careful basically lets people cast unlimited spells until the dimensions run out of energy. I'd recommend having a little bit of Option 1 so that accessing another dimension is tiring and would prevent infinite spell battles. If you want to roll the dice a bit, you could have different dimensions have higher or lower amounts of energy available for spell casting, but the caster doesn't know how much energy is available and could come up short.

Option 3- Charm Laws

'As long as one has the necessary charm for a spell, the spell can be cast.' This might put some restraints on what you can do. For example, Bob needs a special twig for a fire spell, but Bob fell off a waterfall and lost his special twig and dies of hypothermia. This is based off of the Magyk series, but 'charm' could be changed into 'components' if it suits you better.

Option 4- Trigger Laws

'As long as one does the correct trigger(s) for a spell, the spell can be cast' This encompasses weird ominous chants in Latin, waving arms over a fire, and anything else you want it to. So long as the circumstances are right, the spell can be cast. This would also do well with a little bit of Option 1 mixed in so spell casters don't run in circles yelling fireball and defensive spells for hours.

Option 5- Power Object Laws

'If one possesses object(s) with sufficient energy to cast a spell, the spell can be cast.' This would probably be good for limiting powers in spell casting while allowing the character to save his energy for swordfights or whatever. The energy objects should have a limit of power and then a recharge time so that you can't cast spells forever and have to monitor your resources carefully. Of course, the more he wins the more energy objects he will acquire and the more powerful he will get until you've created an unstoppable spell caster. *Writer ye be warned*

Option 6- No Laws

'With our current understanding of the universe, magic cannot be defined.' Offers the most variability with how your spells are cast, but is probably best left this way. If you end up choosing a Law of Magic, it will probably come back to bite you later on. I'd recommend laying out the general story line before choosing a magic law, then see which one works best and change it to your story if you really want to pick one.

For all of these laws a sprinkling of Option 1 and Option 4 would help place limits and make spell battles more interesting, but it's all up to you.

Note- 'energy' can be changed to 'mana' or whatever your spell fuel is.